# Double-Ended Queue: is this a sound "add to front" implementation?

Tags: c++, queue

I'm working on an implementation of the Double-Ended Queue as a Doubly-Linked List (for personal enrichment), and I was wondering if anyone minded taking a look at my PushFront function to see if I'm on the right track.  It should be self-explanatory enough on it's own (I hope).

```
void DeQueue::PushFront(void* item) {
    QueueItem* temp = new QueueItem();
    temp->data = item;
    // Insert the item between the head and the head's next item.
    if (Empty()) {
        head->next = temp;
        tail->last = temp;
        temp->next = tail;
        temp->last = head;
    } else {
        temp->next = head->next;
        temp->last = head;
        head->next->last = temp;
        head->next = temp;
    }
}
```

The idea is that my head and tail sentinels are kept at the ends, which seems to me to be the best way to avoid edge cases.

**EDIT:**  To avoid any confusion, I know this has been done for me in the Standard Library.  I'm doing this as a way to teach myself a few things about the language.

**EDIT:**  It seems I've got the idea.  Now an interesting problem:

```
void* DeQueue::PopFront() {
    if (Empty()) return NULL;  // should throw exception instead.
    void* temp = head->next->data;
    head->next->next->last = head;
    head->next = head->next->next;
    // now my node is gone... How do i free the memory
    // of something I've lost the reference to?
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: What happens if `new` throws an exception?

Comment: Looks like it works to me.  I'd recommend using templates instead of void* though.  Also, assign QueueItem::data in QueueItem's constructor.

Comment: @Als: it looks fine if new throws an exception.  What were you looking for?

Comment: Good thing to remember, thank you.   At the moment I'm not worried about exception handling.  Just the functional bits.

Comment: @MooingDuck:  I was just looking for any pointers and to see if it seemed conceptually accurate.  And I'll add that to the constructor, thank you.

Comment: @MooingDuck: How does it look fine? who catches the exception? It will just call `terminate()`

Comment: @Als: The caller catches the exception.  Or the program terminates.  That's how exceptions work.  This is just like how `std::deque::push_front` can throw `std::bad_alloc` you may notice.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Thanks for that insight(Not that I didn't know it already) but Considering the OP is writing a custom class for deque, my Q aimed at making the OP think about this very detail, From the comment OP made above, looks like S/He never thought of it in first place.

Comment: Did you know about the code review site? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should avoid asking multiple questions in a single entry in stack overflow, it makes it confusing to go over the answers.

Comment: @MarkRansom:  I did not.  Thank you.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas:  Sorry.  I figured that would turn my post into an actual question rather than a "hey look at this code" post.

Comment: @wtfsven: Technically you still don't have a question.  No question marks.

Comment: @MooingDuck:  Yes I do.  It's in the comments in DeQueue::PopFront().  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to second edit: You can't.  You'll have to retain a reference to it.

```
void* DeQueue::PopFront() {
    if (Empty()) 
        throw logic_error("stack is empty");

    QueueItem* deleteme = head->next; //get node
    void* temp = deleteme->data;

    deleteme->next->last = head;
    head->next = deleteme->next;

    delete deleteme; //delete node
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Some more simplification possible there.  Maybe `deleteme->next->last = head;`

Answer (score 2):

About the sentinels, you only need one of them that will contain the `next` (first) and `last` pointers of the list. If you make the pointers refer to the sentinel value during initialization, then you do not need to consider an special case when the list is empty.

About the second question, of pop-ing out of the list, you just need to keep a pointer to the node and call `delete` on it before returning from the function.

Additionally, you might want to consider dividing the problem of learning: use smart pointers to manage your resources and learn the algorithms, then learn memory management (or vice versa)

Comment: I'll definitely take that into consideration.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Seems with this

```
if (Empty()) {
    head->next = temp;
    tail->last = temp;
    temp->next = tail;
    temp->last = head;
```

you presume that head and tail already point to something when the queue is empty?

Comment: `The idea is that my head and tail sentinels are kept at the ends`, he guarantees two sentinel nodes.  This is not an issue, and simplifies a lot of the algorithms.

Comment: I'm assuming head and tail point to each other, which if I do my Pop()s right, they should in that case.  Empty() is determined as "tail->last == head".